# vlookup is not getting the desired data. have two tables with common design number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have two excel sheets.
one having design number and corresponding bar code number to it( a bar code is unique but design number is repeated)

```
design number   bar code
947002035000    1212347
947002035000    1212348
947002041000    1185272
947002041000    1185274
947002041000    1185277
```

the second sheet has only design number in multiple numbers

```
design number  
947002035000
947002041000
947002041000
947002041000
947002041000
947002041000
947002041000
```

issue is when i use `vlookup` formula it gives me multiple same bar code data for one design in second sheet ,i want the barcode to show as unique instead of repeated same number.

```
what i get                           what i wish i can get
design number  barcode               design number     barcode
947002035000   1212347               947002035000      1212347
947002041000   1185272               947002041000      1185272
947002041000   1185272               947002041000      1185274
947002041000   1185272               947002041000      1185277
947002041000   1185272               947002041000      na
947002041000   1185272               947002041000      na
947002041000   1185272               947002041000      na
```

since the data is in thousands of records,doing this is taking a lot of time.

if required i would share the details with you as well for the formula i am using
if anyone can help me in this regard i would be grateful as for next 10 days i have to pull data from around 50 such sheets ..
thanks

update instead of image i have tried to edit this post ..this is first time i am posting here so forgive me if i did make some mistake
thanks

`=VLOOKUP(B368,[BHOJ.xls]Sheet1!B$3:C$32629,2,0)`

Comment: I'm not completely understanding the problem you're facing. Instead of providing your entire workbook and all of your data, can you create a very small (5-10 rows) of data to show what you're trying to do?

Comment: My guess is that you are not getting the values that you need because the design number is repeated. One method to work around this is to create a "helper" column: this column would combine both the design number and the barcode value to create a truly unique value that can be used for lookups. Insert a new column and use a formula such as `=B5176&"-"&C5176` to create a new, unique value that looks like `947002041000-000000001212334`.

Comment: i hope i have updated the post to be much more clearer .. forgive me for my previous unclear post

Comment: Unfortunately, the Excel formulas have no way of knowing which bar code value to use, so it always defaults to the first one. Excel will have to determine when you're looking up the design number if the list of bar codes it finds for that design if zero or some bar code have already been dropped on your second sheet. You're going to have to write your own VBA code in the form of a User Defined Function (UDF). There are a bunch of places to look to figure this out. Just carefully plan each step of what has to happen in order to figure out which bar code you need.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this ARRAY-FOMULA press **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$6,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$6=D2,ROW($B$1:$B$6)),COUNTIF($D$2:$D2;D2)))
```

**UPDATE**
changed counting function to `COUNTIF`. Should work for multiple design numbers now.

[image]

Comment: sorry for delay in reply since i had a lot of sheets to edit,i thought to finish that first.. i am either not able to implement this formula you have suggested or doing some error. each time all i am getting only the first barcode irrespective of any design number that is showing in the list .pls correct me if i am wrong,. #

Comment: just saw our updated formula. will test it and revert in half an hour.. thanks so so much for taking pain to help up..

Comment: =INDEX($D$1:$D$1649,SMALL(IF($C$1:$C$1649=I2,ROW($D$1:$D$1649)),COUNTIF($I$2:$I2;I2)))   tried to use it but gave me a error for the same .. i might sound funny but i am completely not able to use this up.. if you could help it would be great

Comment: @anand aggarwal I also updated the image and used your adapted formula. The results are as expected. Did you enter the formula by pressing all 3 buttons (CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER)?

Comment: yes i did as you told me.. i have been using vlookup for a while so understand this but i guessi am doing something wrong in this